# How to permanently remove or update a VBA reference in excel?

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll, com

My application makes use of macros to generate some charts and this uses references to some of the application dlls. I have converted the whole application from 32-bit to 64-bit including the dlls. But one of these references still seems to refer to 32-bit dll which i was using earlier. Now even when i try adding the new dll file in references it gets named differently and hence i am not able to create objects of this dll from the macros code. It gives me an error saying:
**Automation error: library not registered**

Corresponding code:

```
On Error GoTo errNoDatabase
       Set server = CreateObject("Bemmsdb.Server")
       'server.Connect "SQLOLEDB", "BACKUP", "", "", "Trusted_Connection=Yes"
       'Set db = server.OpenDatabase("BEMMS")
       server.Connect "", "", "", "", ""
       Set db = server.OpenDatabase("")
       GoTo errSkip errNoDatabase:
       MsgBox "Unable to open database. Be sure to select a database in PowerScape before running the 'Query Enetics Database' macro.",
   Title:="Query Enetics Database Macro"
       Exit Sub
```

This gives me the error message at the bottom since it can not create the Bemmsdb.Server object. Can anyone help me with this?

Excel 2013 64bit
Windows 10 64bit
Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Comment: did you develop that dll yourself? is it in C#, (wishful guess, I can see C++ tag). Anyways, one suggestion, add the COM tag and remove macros. you will get more response, hopefully.

Comment: try with Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library checked in tools>references that is

Comment: Have you tried one of the free code cleaners online?  They'll export everything into text files and then rebuild the workbook for you. [Excel VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm)

Comment: @tom I tried doing that but it did not help. I think this is an issue with the dll file i am trying to add to the references. The 64-bit dll gets named as ScriptHost instead of its actual name. Does anyone know which part is responsible for the naming of this library. (I could not find "ScriptHost" in my C++ source code).